# How to upload files to dbinbox.com with curl (bash)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I tried

```
curl -F "file=@/mnt/usb/anime.txt" https://dbinbox.com/galihpa
```

but it gave me

```
curl: (51) Cert verify failed: BADCERT_NOT_TRUSTED
```

I just can't figure out what's wrong. The url I want to post to is `https://dbinbox.com/galihpa`

Please help me..

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Comment: I tried `curl -k -F "file=@/tmp/test.txt" https://dbinbox.com/galihpa` but still didn't work, what's wrong?

Comment: I have no idea. "It didn't work" is not exactly a precise problem description. Was the error the same? If not, what error did you get, or in what way did the result fail to meet your expectations? Did you attempt *any* debugging? And what makes you think that the URL you are using is the correct URL for uploading files? Is there some documentation or are you just guessing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the creator of DBinbox :D

Unfortunately the old API has become depreciated with the recent total rewrite, deployed September 1st. There is currently no predictable way to upload files to DBinbox with curl.

That said, I'm working on a much prettier API that would make this a lot easier. I'll update this answer with documentation when it's ready!

Comment: Thank you. I'll be waiting :D

Comment: Thank you for dbinbox.com ! Has there been any update on the curl command?